# Combining column values with column names using tidyr unite

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I have a `data.frame` with several columns:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(cluster=LETTERS[1:4],group=c(rep("m",2),rep("f",2)),point=rnorm(4),err=runif(4,0.1,0.3))
```

and I'd add another columns which `"\n"` `concatenates` all columns of its respective row, where the column name precedes the value.

I know this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tidyr::unite(df,text,sep="\n")
```

gives me this `tibble`:

```
                                         text
1  A\nm\n0.487429052428485\n0.286941046221182
2  B\nm\n0.738324705129217\n0.142428504256532
3  C\nf\n0.575781351653492\n0.230334753217176
4 D\nf\n-0.305388387156356\n0.125111019192263
```

But what I want is this `tibble`:

```
                                         text
1  cluster: A\ngroup: m\npoint: 0.487429052428485\nerr: 0.286941046221182
2  cluster: B\ngroup: m\npoint: 0.738324705129217\nerr: 0.142428504256532
3  cluster: C\ngroup: f\npoint: 0.575781351653492\nerr: 0.230334753217176
4 cluster: D\ngroup: f\npoint: -0.305388387156356\nerr: 0.125111019192263
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `do.call`

```
data.frame(text = do.call(paste, c(Map(function(x, y) 
                 paste(x, y, sep=": "), names(df), df), sep="\n")))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, map through the columns (`imap` - provides the `.y` as column names) and then do the `unite`

```
library(tidyverse)
imap(df, ~ paste(.y, .x, sep=": ")) %>%
              as_tibble %>%
              unite(text, sep="\n")
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  text                                                                     
#  <chr>                                                                    
#1 "cluster: A\ngroup: m\npoint: -0.626453810742332\nerr: 0.225822808779776"
#2 "cluster: B\ngroup: m\npoint: 0.183643324222082\nerr: 0.112357254093513" 
#3 "cluster: C\ngroup: f\npoint: -0.835628612410047\nerr: 0.14119491497986" 
#4 "cluster: D\ngroup: f\npoint: 1.59528080213779\nerr: 0.135311350505799"
```

---

Or as @DanChaltiel mentioned

```
imap_dfr(df, ~ paste(.y, .x, sep = "; ")) %>%
      unite(text, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: we can also avoid the looping by using `aggregate(do.call(paste,c(sep=" :",rev(stack(df)))),list(c(row(df))),paste,collapse="\n")`

Comment: @Onyambu  Yes but if you check those functions, it does `aggregate`, `stack` etc.  which would be more overhead

Comment: You can even save a call by using `imap_dfr()` and removing `as_tibble`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jared_mamrot's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528862/5002671), another option would be to use `across` to transform the columns to 'column name + column value' first and then `unite` as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(across(names(df), ~paste0(cur_column(), ": ", .x))) %>% unite(text, sep = "\n")

                                                                     text
1 cluster: A\ngroup: m\npoint: -0.626453810742332\nerr: 0.225822808779776
2  cluster: B\ngroup: m\npoint: 0.183643324222082\nerr: 0.112357254093513
3  cluster: C\ngroup: f\npoint: -0.835628612410047\nerr: 0.14119491497986
4   cluster: D\ngroup: f\npoint: 1.59528080213779\nerr: 0.135311350505799
```

This option also allows to select columns of interest easily. Refer to @jared_mamrot's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76528862/5002671).