# Combining column values with column names for some select columns using tidyr unite

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

Given a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = LETTERS[1:4], Col2 = LETTERS[23:26], Col3 = c(1:4), col4 = c(100:103))
```

I want to combine column with their column names. I know I can use `unite` from tidyr and get the following output.

```
df %>% unite(NewCol, c(Col1, Col4), remove = F)

  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 NewCol
1    A    W    1  100  A_100
2    B    X    2  101  B_101
3    C    Y    3  102  C_102
4    D    Z    4  103  D_103
```

But I want to have the column name next to the value of the column as follows (the separator `_` is really not that important):

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 NewCol
1    A    W    1  100  Col1_A_Col4_100
2    B    X    2  101  Col1_B_Col4_101
3    C    Y    3  102  Col1_C_Col4_102
4    D    Z    4  103  Col1_D_Col4_103
```

I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140518/combining-column-values-with-column-names-using-tidyr-unite) which does give the desired output but it creates a separate output.

```
imap_dfr(df %>% select(Col1, Col4), ~ paste(.y, .x, sep = "_")) %>%
  unite(NewCol, sep = "_")

  NewCol         
  <chr>          
1 Col1_A_Col4_100
2 Col1_B_Col4_101
3 Col1_C_Col4_102
4 Col1_D_Col4_103
```

Would I simply use `bind_cols()` to combine both? How do I know the sequence of the rows is preserved between the two? Is there another way that I can create `NewCol` within the same dataframe similar to unite in the first case?

Comment: I don’t understand why you do not test your strategy???

Comment: Is it the `bind_cols()` implementation you're having trouble with? `df %>% bind_cols(imap_dfr(df %>% select(Col1, Col4), ~ paste(.y, .x, sep = "_")) %>% unite(newcol, sep = "_"))` should work as expected. As for "How do I know the sequence of the rows is preserved between the two?" - I can't think of any way that 'newcol' would be in a different order to 'df'

Comment: You could also create the 'colname + value' columns, then unite, then left_join to get the 'overwritten' columns, e.g. `df %>% mutate(across(c(Col1, Col4), ~paste0(cur_column(), "_", .x))) %>% unite(newcol, c(Col1, Col4), sep = "_") %>% left_join(df)`; maybe that would suit better?

Comment: @jared_mamrot - `df %>% mutate(across(c(Col1, Col4), ~paste0(cur_column(), "_", .x))) %>% unite(newcol, c(Col1, Col4), sep = "_") %>% left_join(df)` gives me the desired output with the added peace that row order is preserved. I didn't know about the existence of `cur_column()` until now. I thought the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140518/combining-column-values-with-column-names-using-tidyr-unite) was the way to go.

Comment: @jared_mamrot - Please feel free to post it as solution. I feel your response is a safer way to achieve the desired output (atleast compared to what I was trying to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create temporary 'colname + value' columns, then unite them in a second step, e.g.

```r
## Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

## Load example data
df <- data.frame(Col1 = LETTERS[1:4], Col2 = LETTERS[23:26], Col3 = c(1:4), Col4 = c(100:103))

## Expected outcome
df %>% bind_cols(imap_dfr(df %>% select(Col1, Col4),
                          ~ paste(.y, .x, sep = "_")) %>%
                   unite(newcol, sep = "_"))
#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4          newcol
#> 1    A    W    1  100 Col1_A_Col4_100
#> 2    B    X    2  101 Col1_B_Col4_101
#> 3    C    Y    3  102 Col1_C_Col4_102
#> 4    D    Z    4  103 Col1_D_Col4_103

## With a small number of columns
df %>%
  mutate(tmp_Col1 = paste0("Col1", "_", Col1),
         tmp_Col4 = paste0("Col4", "_", Col4)) %>%
  unite(newcol, c(tmp_Col1, tmp_Col4), sep = "_")
#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4          newcol
#> 1    A    W    1  100 Col1_A_Col4_100
#> 2    B    X    2  101 Col1_B_Col4_101
#> 3    C    Y    3  102 Col1_C_Col4_102
#> 4    D    Z    4  103 Col1_D_Col4_103

## With a large number of columns
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(Col1, Col4),
                ~paste0(cur_column(), "_", .x))) %>%
  unite(newcol, c(Col1, Col4), sep = "_") %>%
  left_join(df)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(Col2, Col3)`
#>            newcol Col2 Col3 Col1 Col4
#> 1 Col1_A_Col4_100    W    1    A  100
#> 2 Col1_B_Col4_101    X    2    B  101
#> 3 Col1_C_Col4_102    Y    3    C  102
#> 4 Col1_D_Col4_103    Z    4    D  103
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you have a large number of columns you want to transform, using `across()` allows you to employ [tidyselect functions](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html), such as `starts_with()`, to select columns of interest without having to specify each column by name.